# Bounty recipient in revision history has the wrong font size

Tags: bug, design, revisions-list

Random example here, but all awarded bounties exhibit the problem:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/242517/revisions
>   [image]

The link to the answer ("`Infinite Recursion's answer`") is too large.

The `.answer-hyperlink, .question-hyperlink` element has `font-size: 16px;` in its style. Removing that solves this most critical bug.